# Pesquisar imagens em todo os subdirectorios

Tags: c#

Preciso procurar por imagens em todos os subdiretórios e apresentá-las numa `picturebox`, porém o código que tenho atualmente só me permite procurar numa única pasta e sem filtrar por tipos de ficheiros como por exemplo `*jpg`, `*png`, etc...

Segue abaixo meu código:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace _myfotospf
{
    public partial class FormFotos1 : Form
    {
        public FormFotos1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormFotos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\...\Imagens");
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Nome do ficheiro (duplo clique para ver a miniatura)");
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files[i]);
                table.Rows.Add(file.Name);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormFotos2 myForm = new FormFotos2();
            string imageName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            Image img;
            img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\...\Imagens\" + imageName);
            myForm.pictureBox1.Image = img;
            myForm.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode retornar um **IEnumerable** com os diretórios dos seus arquivos. Esse método que estou te passando irá buscar no diretório raiz e nos subdiretórios a partir do caminho informado.

Primeiro parâmetro é o diretório raiz que deseja iniciar a busca por seus arquivos.

Segundo parâmetro é o padrão de busca de arquivos, nesse caso estamos dizendo para buscar todos os arquivos de todas as extensões.

Terceiro parâmetro estamos dizendo que iremos procurar em todos os subdiretórios a partir do nosso caminho raiz.

A cláusula Where do Linq é para filtrarmos os arquivos que possuam as extensões que desejamos encontrar, no seu caso deseja **jpg** ou **png**. Caso queira inserir mais uma extensão, basta adicionar mais uma condição **OR** com a extensão desejada.

```
IEnumerable<string> arquivos = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Imagens", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(w => w.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg") || w.ToLower().EndsWith(".png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Penso que esta solução é bastante abrangente:

```
// se pretender ter várias pastas
List<string> diretorios = new List<string>()
{
    @"C:\Pasta1",
    @"C:\Pasta2",
    @"C:\Pasta3"
};

// se pretender pesquisar várias extensões
// é necessário ter um ponto antes da extensão
List<string> extensoes = new List<string>()
{
    ".jpg",
    ".bmp",
    ".png",
    ".tiff",
    ".gif"
};

private void FormFotos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    table.Columns.Add("Nome do ficheiro (duplo clique para ver a miniatura)");

    foreach (string diretorio in diretorios)
    {
        var ficheiros = Directory.EnumerateFiles(diretorio, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
            Where(r => extensoes.Contains(Path.GetExtension(r.ToLower())));

        foreach (var ficheiro in ficheiros)
            table.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(ficheiro));
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Comment: João Martins, Obrigado. Agora não surgem os resultados no datagridview

Comment: Certo, faltava um ponto "." antes de cada extensão quando declaramos a lista `extensoes`. Editei o código e assim já deve funcionar!

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Eu nem reparei nesse pormenor. O problema é que os resultados surgem na datagridview mas quando faço duplo clique na tabela para visualizar as imagens, elas não surgem.             FormFotos2 myForm = new FormFotos2();
            string imageName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            Image img;
            img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\...\...\...\...\" + imageName);
            myForm.pictureBox1.Image = img;
            myForm.ShowDialog();

Comment: Valide se o caminho para a imagem fica correto quando faz o `Image.FromFile`.

Comment: Quando as imagens estão na raiz do diretório, surgem, mas quando estão dentro de outras subpastas, dá erro: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=C:\...\...\...\...\20170301_102446.jpg

Comment: Na variável `diretorios` só precisa colocar um diretório, senão ele vai fazer 3 vezes a mesma coisa desnecessariamente. Quanto ao problema do caminho, coloque o caminho absoluto ao invés do caminho relativo.

Comment: O caminho já é absoluto. Eu é que eliminei os nomes das pastas.

Comment: Então há algum erro no próprio caminho. O erro é bastante explícito `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: As imagens só não surgem se estiverem dentro de subpastas. Não sei como resolver isto.

Comment: Se colocar o caminho manualmente nesta linha `Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\...\Imagens\" + imageName);`, continua sem funcionar?

Comment: João Martins, obrigado uma vez mais pela ajuda. Não funciona. A picturebox só devolve a imagem se ela estiver na pasta raíz que eu aponto no caminho. Se a imagem estiver dentro de subpastas, já não surge. Estou a dar voltas á cabeça e não encontro o motivo.

Comment: Será permissões de acesso? Já tentou aceder ao Visual Studio como Administrador?

Comment: Não é permissões. Já tinha testado. O problema é que o caminho para o ficheiro não fica correto se a imagem estiver dentro de outra pasta. Tipo: se a imagem x estiver na pasta A, ela surge na picturebox, mas se a imagem y estiver dentro da pasta B que por sua vez está dentro da pasta A, já dá erro. A picturebox não está a ir buscar o caminho correto.

Comment: Quando diz que o caminho para o ficheiro não fica correto quando estiver dentro de outra pasta, o que quer dizer ao certo? Como é que fica o caminho? Pode dar um exemplo real?

Comment: Imaginemos que tenho estes ficheiros:
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Imagens\img001.jpg
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Imagens\2018\img002.jpg
O caminho que está definido é:
img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Imagens\" + imageName);
O ficheiro img001.jpg surge na picturebox quando faço duplo clique na datagridview, mas a imagem img002.jpg já não surge (dá erro), isto porque o duplo clique na datagridview devolve sempre um caminho para a pasta raíz, tipo:
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Imagens\img002.jpg